# Why Angular HttpClient is not sending OPTIONS call?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make a call to an external API.  I am getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` because pre-flight is failing, as the request is not first firing off an OPTIONS call.  I don't quite understand why this is happening.  I have confirmed that the server can receive CORS requests.

```
  public onSubmitUserDetails(value) {
    const httpBody = {content: "whatevercontent"}
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
      })
    };
    const post = this.httpClient.post("https://whateverdomain.com", httpBody, httpOptions);
    post.subscribe();
  }
```

This is the network request (no options call!)
[image]

More network detail from console
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. OPTIONS request it's not about Angular or another framework. Whether browser sends an OPTIONS request is exactly specified by the [CORS specfication](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). If your request is [simple](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-method), contains only [simple headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-header) and the [force preflight flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#force-preflight-flag) is unset no OPTIONS request will be sent.
2. You should not send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the client side. You should receive it from the server and it should either contain your client-side domain or `*`. Otherwise, the browser will not allow you to get the response data.

My answer could be more detailed if you provide more information about server responses you get.

Comment: Actually, response headers are more informative in this case. And, as you see, OPTIONS request has been sent

Comment: Oh man, it only sent options, and this whole time i thought it didn't send!

Comment: It sents OPTIONS, doesn't get your domain in response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and then stops. I'd propose you to look for the issue on the server-side, not the client. But to be sure, let's look at response headers of OPTIONS request. (I didn't downvote your question, (just in case))

Comment: It returns "This request has no response data attached"... To confirm it works (although maybe not with localhost?) I did a POST call with https://reqbin.com/ and it returns data

Comment: You should have response headers in Dev Tools same as you've just added the screenshot with request headers

Comment: You've posted the screenshot of response body but I'm asking you for response headers. They are on `Headers` tab same as request headers